# cellForRowAtIndexPath being called very late

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to fetch JSON data from OpenWeatherMap API depending on user location and display it in a tableview.

First, I just init my table view :

```
init(_ coder: NSCoder? = nil) {
    self.tableView = UITableView()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad I call a function `launchLocationOperations()` to get user's location :

```
func launchLocationOperations() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

In my delegate :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let locationArray = locations as NSArray
    let currentLocation = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    if self.currentCoordinates == nil ||
        (self.currentCoordinates?.latitude != currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            ||
            self.currentCoordinates?.longitude != currentLocation.coordinate.longitude) {
        self.currentCoordinates = currentLocation.coordinate
        self.hasLoadedCoordinates = true
        self.fetchWeatherInformations()
    }
}
```

Then calling `fetchWeatherInformation()` :

```
func fetchWeatherInformations() {
    // I build my path
    let urlPath = StringUtils.buildUrl(self.currentCoordinates)
    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        do {
            let jsonResponse = try data?.toJSON() as? [String : Any]
            self.openWeatherMapResponse = OpenWeatherMapResponse.convert(jsonResponse: jsonResponse)
            self.displayUI()
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching JSON response : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And in `displayUI()` :

```
func displayUI() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

So I have two problems here :

- First, `didUpdateLocations` is being called many times even if I ask to `stopUpdatingLocation()` when entering the function.
- Second, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called very, very late, like 5 seconds late. I don't know why it is happening because the other `dataSource`/`delegate` methods are called instantly after entering `displayUI()`...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the benefit to set datasource and delegate in `displayUI()`? You should set both (once) right after creating the table view and call `reloadData()` to update the UI.

Comment: Did you try calling displayUI() method on main thread like DispatchQueue.main.async { self.displayUI() }

Comment: @vadian You are right, I have set `dataSource` and `delegate` in `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: @Aakash Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem! I just understood that I was trying to update the UI outside from the main thread... thanks again.